# Are threads the code itself or some entity?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to understand `Thread` a little more. I understand that in Java we can created a `Thread` by either extending a `Thread` class or implementing `Runnable` interface.

My doubt is:

Is "Thread" the "code" itself which it executes OR is "Thread" like a "thing" which executes the code?

Comment: Thread is rather assignment of CPU time with isolated call stack

Comment: In Java, [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) is a class. A thread needs a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html), which it executes.

Comment: Are you asking about `java.lang.Thread` (a concrete Java class), or are you asking about the concept of (multi-)threading? Also, what's the difference between "code" and "thing"(s) that execute code?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I mainly work in java, but i have this intrinsic doubt. So I took this "risk" of asking, rather being confused all the time. I admit I am a learner.

Comment: The entire idea of object-oriented programming is to write code (e.g., `java.lang.Thread`) that serves as the tangible representation of some concept or meatspace object (a thread of execution).

Comment: BTW "Thing that executes code" is usually called CPU...

Comment: @Antoniossss Java code is compiled to a byte-code and then executed by a Java runtime environment on an operating system which is responsible for scheduling processes to execute for a particular amount of time on a CPU. So "thing that executes code" could be a JRE, a process, an operating system **or** a CPU. Notice I managed to never once use the word "thread" there.

Comment: nah its CPU always as system is imaginary while CPU is the physical executor. At least thats what i meant

Comment: @Antoniossss [Sometimes](https://monster6502.com/). And sometimes [not](http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/index.html).

Comment: Always not sometimes. inbetween layers does not matter as it does not exists without hardware.

Answer (score 4):

*Threads*, in the abstract, are an operating-system feature that allows multiple paths of code execution, sometimes running simultaneously in parallel (if the hardware supports that) or other times running in parallel via time-slicing (the OS suspending one thread and giving another one time to run), or usually (these days) a combination of those two things: Your computer might have 200 threads running, of which only 4-8 are running simultaneously because that's all the hardware allows, for instance.

Java provides the `Thread` class with which you can create a thread and have code run on that thread. The `Thread` instance and the OS thread are not the same thing. The `Thread` instance provides a way to schedule code to run on a separate OS thread.

Probably one way to make that distinction clear is to **mis**-use `Thread`:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...do some work...
    }
}

var t = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
t.run(); // WRONG
```

Although that creates a `Thread` object, the code in `run` does **not** run on a separate thread. It runs on the thread calling `run`. The thread created by the `Thread` instance is not used at all.

Hopefully that illustrates the distinction between the `Thread` instance and the actual OS thread.

For completeness, here's the correct way to do it:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...do some work...
    }
}

var t = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
t.start(); // ***
```

After the call to `start`, the thread making that call continues, and **separately** the new thread running the code in `run` executes in parallel. `start` is what works with the OS to schedule the call to `run` to happen on a separate thread from the thread `start` is running on.

Comment: I have to disappear, so I've marked this CW -- please, anyone, feel free to improve it via the "edit" link, or feel free to take any part of the above that may be useful and build it into your own non-CW answer.

Comment: Can anyone explain this phrase: The ```Thread``` instance and the OS thread are not the same thing. The ```Thread```instance provides a way to schedule code to run on a separate OS thread.

Comment: @DanielK IBM [Understanding Java and native thread details](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.15/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/javadump_tags_javaandnative_thread_detail.html) says (in part) *A Java thread runs on a native thread, which means that two stack traces exist for each Java thread. The first stack trace shows the Java methods and the second stack trace shows the native functions.* An "OS thread" is another way to say a "native thread".